# Почему у меня не запускается данный код на python?

Tags: python

```
import random
die1 = random.randit(1, 6)
die2 = random.randrange(6) + 1
total = die1 + die2
print("Вам выпало", die1, "и", die2, "очков. В сумме", total)
input("\n\nНажмите Enter, чтобы выйти")
```

Answer (score 1):

в методе `randint` вы допустили опечатку и забыли букву `n`

замените `randit` на `randint`

Answer (score 1):

```
die1 = random.randint(1, 6)
```

Пропустил `n` в `randit(1, 6)`

Comment: а можно пример???